# Android - Correct Multithreading / UI updating

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous

I have an application that will be accessing the web. I've decided to use Spring Android as the RestAPI, and with the help of a `Thread` have got this simple demo working. My question is, how do I go about changing it to populating an actual `ListView` rather than just logging the output of the object? Some other questions on here have led me to believe that `AsyncTask` may be the answer, but I'm still a bit confused as to how I update the UI, as it is my understanding that other threads can't touch it.

Here is what I have now, minus the function that creates the RestTemplate, and makes the request, as I believe it is not relevant:

```
  public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
  {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    new Thread( new Runnable() {
      public void run()
      {
        // create a RestTemplate. This is used to communicate with the server.
        RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();

        String url = "http://192.168.2.14:8888/";

        JSONData[] jsonData = restTemplate.getForObject( url, JSONData[].class );

        for( JSONData d : jsonData )
        {
          Log.d( "TEST", d.getName() + " " + d.getId() );
        }
      }
    } ).start();

    setContentView( R.layout.main );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, listed in the very nice article [(Android) Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).
`AsyncTask` is one of the options and it seems to fit your needs, and there are several methods of it that run on the UI thread, such as `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that Painless Threading article is exactly what I needed. `AsyncTask` it is!

Answer (score 4):

if want to change the UI from a different thread, you can use Handler or Activity.runOnUiThread().